# How to use try command in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL world. I am writing a script which has 5 steps. In each step I am souring a TCL script. While source TCL script 2 in step 2 if i get error i need to skip to last step. Could you please help me how to use try {} command. Below is the sample script i have uses

```
 try {
      try {
         source script 1
       } on error {
          mail the error message
       }
      ....
      try {
         source script 6
       } on error {
          mail the error message
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd write

```
  try {
     source script 1
     source script 2
     source script 3
     source script 4
     source script 5
   } on error {errmsg erropts} {
      mail the error message
   }
```

You need to provide a *variable list* (even an empty one) for `on error` -- see the [`try` documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm)

---

Here's a flexible approach: put the email details in a dictionary, keyed by the script name:

```
set scripts [dict create {*}{
  "script 1" {
    subject "the email subject for script 1"
    body "the email body for script 1"
  }
  #and so on for other scripts
}]

# Now, iterate over the dictionary and try sourcing each one
dict for {scriptname email} $scripts {
  try {
    source $scriptname
  } on error err {
    dict with email {
      send email with $subject and $body and error message $err
    }
  }
}
```

---

To stop looping after the first error, add a `break` in the catch body:

```
dict for {scriptname email} $scripts {
  try {
    source $scriptname
  } on error err {
    dict with email {
      send email with $subject and $body and error message $err
    }
    break   ;# do not proceed to the next script
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply but i need to send different mail for different script exited.  Will the same script will helpful

Comment: Hi Glen i have tried the above script but still after script 1 exits with error it is sourcing the script 2

Comment: Thanks Glenn its working now

Comment: Hi Glenn one more doubt can we give variable to value, Currently it is display with $VARIABLE only instead of "valye of varible"